# using object as parameter for find in meteor bears no result

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I got the following code:

```
Clientes = new Meteor.Collection 'clientes'

 Template.listaClientes.clientes = ->   
 query = {}
 query = Session.get "searchData"
 console.log "get: " + query.nombre  
 clientes = Clientes.find(query) 

 Template.listaClientes.events
  'click .listItem' : ->
     console.log "item clicked"

 Template.searchPane.events
 'click #btnToList' : ->
     query = {}
     #asigna los campos a query si no son blancos
     if (x = $("#qNombre").val())? then query.nombre = x
     if (x = $("#qCiudad").val())? then query.ciudad = x
     console.log "q: " + query.nombre + query.ciudad    

     Session.set "searchData", query
```

it runs perfect on startup, query is {} so template shows every document in the collection. When I click on #btnToList I get no results back from the Find clausule. If I set "searchData" to {} manually from browser console it fires the trigger and all documents are drawn again.

any ideas about what I'm missing?

edit:
Doing the following works fine which makes me wonder whats going on even more :/

```
  q={}
  q.nombre = query.nombre if query.nombre?
  Clientes.find q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, looks like the second IF (#qCiudad) was always adding a value even when empty.
Changing the checks to if (x = $("#qCiudad).val()) != "" then ...  made it and the query objects is passed correctly.